# HTML: anchor attribute when pointing to index file

Tags: html, anchor, href

Considering leaving the href attribute empty for anchor tags is not a best-practice, how do I go about doing that "legally"?

I don't want to link to index.html or index.php or such, I want to link to the default index file in that document.

Setting it to `/` does the trick if you are in the root, otherwise it will still go there so it's not a solution.

How should I do this?

Thank you.

Comment: how come no one ever voted up for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to link to the default document at your current directory, this should be valid:

```
<a href="./">My Directory's Default Document</a>
```

If you just wish to have an anchor tag that does not leave the current page:

```
<a href="#">Go Nowhere</a>
```

Comment: That second link doesn't go nowhere, it goes to the top of the page. (If you do want a link that goes nowhere, then you need to stop wanting that)

Comment: The later is the norm for non-directional hrefs. I would go for that if I were you :-)

Comment: The question isn't asking for a non-directional href. It asks for a link to the index. e.g. from /foo/bar.html to /foo/. Non-directional hrefs are simply wrong.

Comment: @david Yes, you're quite right.  Semantically, it's all kinds of wrong.  But it's the closest thing we have to an anchor with no destination, which can often be useful for page mock-ups and such.

Comment: @david Also, point taken about "#" taking you to the top of the page.  I've edited my answer to be more accurate.

Answer (score 2):

Try linking to ./ - think that should do it

Answer (score 0):

Consider doing it server side.

You can create a function in PHP (causes that's what you are using, right) that would take the current URL and add the current directory and render that.

Do include the domain as they say it is good for SEO.